# Can you grant an Active Directory Group rights on a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to grant rights to an Active Directory Group on a Linked Server. I am unable to do it; it only allows me to grant rights to individual active directory users. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by creating a role for the AD Group user and assigning permissions to it.

1. Create your Active Directory Group as a login in SQL Server as below :

   ```
   USE master;
   GO
   CREATE LOGIN [COMPANYDOMAIN\ADGroup] FROM WINDOWS;
   GO
   ```
2. Then create a user from the login in the database

   ```
   USE DatabaseName;
   GO
   CREATE USER [COMPANYDOMAIN\ADGroup] FROM LOGIN [COMPANYDOMAIN\ADGroup];
   GO
   ```
3. Now Grant appropriate permissions to the user

   Note: Granting a server permission to a database role is not possible

   ```
   GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.XP_PROP_OLEDB_PROVIDER to [COMPANYDOMAIN\ADGroup];
   ```

Comment: Doesn't this grant permissions to see the available linked servers, rather than grant permissions to use a *specific* linked server?